# How to call web3.js functions synchronous

Tags: web3js, nodejs, command-line

Installed web3.js 1.0.0-beta.26 on macOS
Running testrpc, Node.js based Ethereum client

After running node in my terminal and initiating the web3 object listening to port 8545:

```
> var Web3 = require("web3")
> web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")
```

I can only see my lists of accounts asynchronous like:

```
> web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log)
```

I want to do it synchronous like:

```
> web3.eth.accounts
```

Also for example `web3.eth.getBalance()` returns a promise. Where I before was able to run it synchronous.

I want to execute it like in this video: https://youtu.be/-5LhwoCcjp0?t=1m15s 
Is this because I have installed the latest version or is there a possibility to run it synchronous.

Comment: What is the error message when you execute `web3.eth.accounts`?

Comment: @Malone No error message. I get an accounts object. But I installed a previous version where I can use web3.eth.accounts and get the array of accounts. So I think it has to do with the new version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently web3 v1.0 only supports asynchronous operations.

You can install the previous version if you want synchronous behavior.

> npm install web3@0.20